# Google Big Query array aggregation with sum

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

SQL beginner here.

```
WITH vals AS
  (
    SELECT 1 x, 'a' y, 120 z UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 x, 'a' y, 359 z UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 x, 'b' y, 130 z UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 x, 'a' y, 140 z UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 x, 'c' y, 160 z
  )
SELECT x, ARRAY_AGG(y) as array_aggy,  ARRAY_AGG(z) as array_aggz
FROM vals
GROUP BY x;
```

The output of this query is

```
Row     x         array_aggy    array_aggz  
1       1             a            120
                      a            359
                      b            130

2       2             a            140
                      c            160
```

I want to sum array_aggz values if they have the same value in array_aggy

```
Row     x         array_aggy    array_aggz  
1       1             a            479
                      b            130

2       2             a            140
                      c            160
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below

```
select x, array_agg(y) as array_aggy,  array_agg(aggz) as array_aggz
from (
  select x, y, sum(z) aggz
  from vals
  group by x, y    
)
group by x
```

with output

[image]

Comment: have you tried?